# How to apply a class method to chunks of a pandas dataframe in parallel?

Tags: pandas, parallel-processing, joblib

I have a dataframe `df` that I would like to break into smaller chunks **column wise** so that I can apply a class method to each chunk. The method seems to work fine, but then after around 10 iterations I keep getting `CustomizablePickler(buffer, self._reducers).dump(obj), AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'delayed.<locals>.delayed_function'`, so I am not sure what's wrong.

What I have so far

```
from typing import Tuple

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self.df = df
    ...
    def run(self) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
        <operate on self.df>


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from joblib import Parallel, delayed
    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

    n_cpu = 6
    chunk = df.shape[1] // n_cpu
    # create chunk column indicies
    lower_idx = np.array([0, chunk, 2 * chunk, 3 * chunk, 4 * chunk, 5 * chunk])
    upper_idx = lower_idx + chunk
    upper_idx[-1] = df.shape[1]
    res = Parallel(n_jobs=n_cpu, backend="multiprocessing")(
        delayed(MyClass(df.iloc[:, i: j]).run()) for i, j in zip(lower_idx, upper_idx)
    )
```

The dataframe `df` is small and can easily fit in memory (only 54 Mb), but the operations in `run()` take a long time, so I would like to parallelise these operations over a subset of columns of `df` at a time.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there an easier to way to do this? I don't need to use the `joblib` package, but I would like to leave `MyClass` unchanged if possible.

Comment: What should be the expect result? A list of `MyClass` instances or the result of the `run` method?

Comment: @Corralien `run()` returns a 2-tuple of numpy ndarrays. I'll edit the code in the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proxy function to run your class instance:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from typing import Tuple

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self.df = df

    def run(self) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
        return (df.min(1).values, df.max(1).values)

def proxy(df):
    c = MyClass(df)
    return c.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.random.seed(2022)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 1000, (10, 100)))

    n_cpu = 6
    chunks = np.array_split(df, n_cpu, axis=1)

    with mp.Pool(n_cpu) as pool:
        data = pool.map(proxy, chunks)
```

Output:

```
>>> data
[(array([12, 15,  1,  4, 13,  3,  9,  2, 41, 16]),
  array([998, 981, 986, 991, 969, 995, 976, 996, 998, 995])),
 (array([12, 15,  1,  4, 13,  3,  9,  2, 41, 16]),
  array([998, 981, 986, 991, 969, 995, 976, 996, 998, 995])),
 (array([12, 15,  1,  4, 13,  3,  9,  2, 41, 16]),
  array([998, 981, 986, 991, 969, 995, 976, 996, 998, 995])),
 (array([12, 15,  1,  4, 13,  3,  9,  2, 41, 16]),
  array([998, 981, 986, 991, 969, 995, 976, 996, 998, 995])),
 (array([12, 15,  1,  4, 13,  3,  9,  2, 41, 16]),
  array([998, 981, 986, 991, 969, 995, 976, 996, 998, 995])),
 (array([12, 15,  1,  4, 13,  3,  9,  2, 41, 16]),
  array([998, 981, 986, 991, 969, 995, 976, 996, 998, 995]))]
```

**Update**

Can you replace the `with` block by:

```
    p = mp.get_context('fork').Pool(8)
    data = p.map(proxy, chunks)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good solution. Although it doesn't work on my hardware - I get `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function proxy at 0x1183b4a60>: attribute lookup proxy on __main__ failed`. It could either be because I'm using python 3.9 or because I'm running on a Mac M1 chip.

Comment: I think it's a problem with your Mac M1 chip. It runs perfectly with Python 3.9 on Linux.

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible workaround. Can you check it please?

Comment: It's the same pickle issue as before. But thanks for the update and for the solution. I've had other problems running certain python packages on the M1, so most likely that is the issue here. I'll accept this answer. Thanks again

Comment: I hope you can solve this problem. Thanks